# Define a function with nested functions and default function

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function test() {
    this.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo');
        return;
    }

    this.bar = function() {
        console.log('bar');
        return;
    }
}

var action = new test();
action.foo();    //prints 'foo'
```

Code above works fine in case I need to call an action `foo` or `bar` inside action `test`. However action `test` itself supposed to be a callable function. I thought it would be cool if JavaScript would let me create something like this (see below) but, as expected, says:

> TypeError: action is not a function

```
function test() {
    this.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo');
        return;
    }

    this.bar = function() {
        console.log('bar');
        return;
    }

    return function() {
        console.log('default');
        return;
    }();
}

var action= new test();
action();        //prints 'default'
action.bar();    //printf 'bar'
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. Just create a function inside and add other properties directly to the function object:

```js
function test() {
  
    var result = function () {
        console.log('default');
    };
  
    result.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo');
        return;
    }

    result.bar = function() {
        console.log('bar');
        return;
    }

    return result;
}

var test = new test();
test();        //prints 'default'
test.bar();    //printf 'bar'
```

Comment: Can these function prototyping be nested as well? Say, `test.foo` is actually a function with possible methods like `test.foo.buzz` or `test.foo.bar`.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript it is possible to add properties also to functions. So that you can do something like this:

```
function test() {
    function defaultFn() {
       console.log('default');
    }
    defaultFn.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo');
        return;
    }
    defaultFn.bar = function() {
        console.log('bar');
        return;
    }
    return defaultFn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While others that pointed out that this is possible, I just wanted to point out that it is generally a bad practice to have constructor functions return an object that isn't the instance created by `new`.

Looking at your example:

```
function Test() {
    this.foo = function() {}

    this.bar = function() {}

    return function() {}();
}

var test = new Test();
```

(I renamed your `test` function to `Test` because it is a convention to uppercase functions that you expect to be called with `new`)

What JS does when you call `new Test()` is that it makes a new Object instance `{}` and passes it into the `Test()` function as the `this` context. By default, this object is also what is returned by the call to `new`.

So what you are doing is attaching `foo` and `bar` functions to that newly created object isntance.

Then you `return` a different function, which then gets returned from the call to `new Test()` instead of the object instance that has `foo` and `bar` on it... that object is just lost/garbage collected.

This "returning a different object from a constructor function" is bad practice and leads to confusion. Plus this happens:

```
function Test() {}

var test = new Test();
test instanceof Test; // returns TRUE
```

however if you return something else:

```
function Test() {
  return function() {};
}

var test = new Test();
test instanceof Test; // returns FALSE (confusing!!!)
```

---

It would be cleaner to avoid the `new` and just do:

```
function test() {
    var newFunc = function() {
        console.log('default');
        return;
    };

    newFunc.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo');
        return;
    }

    newFunc.bar = function() {
        console.log('bar');
        return;
    }

    return newFunc;
}

var t = test();
t();      // default
t.foo();  // foo
t.bar();  // bar
```

Comment: This is really a good explanation about returning an object other than `this` and deserves an upvote, however in particularly my case doing so was just for showcase sake, to show what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It will call the code below as soon as you create the instance of that function. Like _constructor.

```
return function() {
        console.log('default');
        return;
    }();
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, I misunderstood the parser error and it compiles fine, however overriding constructor was not the goal I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like the following:

```
function userClass(name, func) {
    this.name = name;
    this.func = func;    
}

function test(flag) {
    this.foo = function() {
        console.log('foo');
        return;
    }

    this.bar = function() {
        alert('bar');
        return;
    }

    return function() {
            var obj = {};
        obj["bar"] = new userClass("bar", function(){alert('bar');});
        alert('default');
        return obj;
    }();
}

var test = new test();
//test();        //prints 'default'
console.log(test);
test.bar.func();    //printf 'bar'
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DlanorJQ/8u72zdc9/)